# How to save jQuery cloned text input to cookie or html5 storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage, web-storage

I have a text input and when user is click on button the jQuery clone input and make another one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.add').click(function(event){
    var predmet = $('input.clear:last');
    $('div.clear').before(predmet.clone().val('').slideToggle( "fast" ));
    $('div.clear').before(predmet.next().clone().val(0));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now, my question is - How i can save input forms to cookie or html5 storage (what is better solution?). I want when is page refresh to appear cloned text input ,who have previously saved with cookie or html5. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of objects that can be saved to localStorage using `JSON.stringify()` during save, and `JSON.parse()` during retrieval to return string to array.

What you save will depend a bit on your UI needs.

The very simplest format of this array can  be easily obtained using jQuery `serializeArray()`. If you need more detail like label value, display settings etc you would need to create your own objects for the array

Thus you could do:

```
var data = $('#formID').serializeArray();
localStorage.setItem('myFormData', JSON.stringify( data));
```

Then on page load, retrieve string from localStorage, return it to array using `JSON.parse` and loop over array to create your fields

**[jQUery serializeArray() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)**

Comment: Thank you! I understand it but i can't make it... Is there a fiddle or example code of that? I only want to save create text input and value and backup to local storage, so when page is refres to get values and forms back.

Comment: you create the fiddle with your basic add functionality...can help from there

Comment: Is there a jquery plugin i can use for this?

Comment: is quite simple to build... no idea if plugin exists or not...doesn't take much code. Put your basic html and `add` function in fiddle.net and save it...will help

Comment: try this  http://jsfiddle.net/5JR7L/1/ Is working when you make changes, click `Store Data`...and hit `Run` again in top of fiddle menu

Comment: Wow, it's nice, thank you! Can i hide the code after i click store data?

Comment: Can i have button who delete cloned text input? It will be nice. Thanks!

Comment: code is only displayed for reference...just remove that line..here's a delete too  http://jsfiddle.net/5JR7L/2/

Comment: Thanks! Can i restrict numbers so user can only input numbers from 1 to 5 in text input?

Answer (score 0):

html5 storage is a good choice if your user base is likely to have HTML storage available. Cookie storage is better if you have to support old browsers.